How to get a count of in a SQL subquery
I am working on the following SQL where I am getting a few values using a sub query; I need to get another value, but that has some different conditions:
SELECT Operator,
       COUNT(*) AS 'Sales',
       SUM(Commission) As 'Commission', 
       SUM(Fee + (2 * Commission)) As 'Amount',
       SUM(Prem) As 'Prem',
FROM (
    SELECT F.FormId,
           F.Prem,
           F.Agent,
           ((F.Prem/(1 + (112/100.00))) * ((PLS.Commission/100.00) * 50/100.00)) As 'Commission',
    CASE WHEN F.Prem!= PLPT.Charged THEN  ((F.Prem - PLPT.Charged) * (13.11/100.00)) 
         ELSE 0 
         END As 'Fee'
    FROM FORM F
    INNER JOIN PaymentTransaction PLPT ON F.FormId = PLPT.FormId
    INNER JOIN PublicScheme_backup PLS ON PLS.SchemeId = PLPT.SchemeId
    WHERE Agent IS NOT NULL 
    AND F.TranTypeId= 6
    AND Convert( date, F.Timestamp) BETWEEN '01 Jun 2024' AND '04 Jul 2024'
    AND F.FormId > 1950000 
) As X
GROUP BY Operator

The above query Operator name, Sale count, commission, amount, prem
Operator    Sales   Commission  Amount      Prem
--------------------------------------------------
8E          3       33.547300   94.640021   319.77

In this task need to get count of records where TranTypeId = 7 which will be labeled as Quotes but that should be based on every operator (grouped by operator) and given date range:
Operator    Sales   Commission  Amount      Prem    Quotes
------------------------------------------------------------------
8E          3       33.547300   94.640021   319.77  Expected value

I have tried the following statement:
SELECT Operator,
        Count(*) AS 'Sales',
        SUM(Commission) AS 'Commission', 
        SUM(Fee + (2 * Commission)) AS 'Amount',
        SUM(Prem) AS 'Prem',
        (SELECT Count(*) 
         FROM Form 
         WHERE TranTypeId = 7 
              AND Convert(date,Datetimestamp)  BETWEEN '01 Jun 2024' AND '04 Jul 2024' 
              AND Operator = Operator
        ) AS 'Quotes'
FROM (
    SELECT F.FormId, 
           F.Prem,
           F.Agent,
           ((F.Prem/(1 + (112/100.00))) * ((PLS.Commission/100.00) * 50/100.00)) AS 'Commission',
           CASE WHEN F.Prem!= PLPT.Charged THEN  ((F.Prem - PLPT.Charged) * (13.11/100.00)) 
                ELSE 0 
                END AS 'Fee'
    FROM FORM F
    INNER JOIN PaymentTransaction PLPT ON F.FormId = PLPT.FormId
    INNER JOIN PublicScheme_backup PLS ON PLS.SchemeId = PLPT.SchemeId
    WHERE Agent IS NOT NULL 
          AND F.TranTypeId= 6
          AND Convert(date,F.Timestamp) BETWEEN '01 Jun 2024' AND '04 Jul 2024'
          AND F.FormId > 1950000 
) AS X
GROUP BY Operator

but I'm not getting the expected result - I'm getting the same quote count for each operator

Operator = Operator is probably not what you want. You need to join the inner X table operator or whatever

@siggemannen can i use alias to subquery FS.Agent = X.Agent

You may need to use a conditional aggregation as follows :
SELECT Operator,
        Count(*) AS 'Sales',
        SUM(Commission) AS 'Commission', 
        SUM(Fee + (2 * Commission)) AS 'Amount',
        SUM(Prem) AS 'Prem',
        SUM(CASE WHEN TranTypeId = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Quotes'
FROM (
    -- Your subquery
) AS X
GROUP BY Operator

